# Doubly linked list doesn't print out the final element; Pretty sure it has to do with my != operator overload

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

I'm a beginner that's having some difficulty overloading the "!=" operator for iterators. It's a standard doubly linked list with nodes.
This is my relevant code for the operator overloading of !=:

```
Node *ptr;

bool operator != (const list_iterator& itr) const {return this->ptr != itr.ptr;}
```

The problem is, when I print with

```
Essay::iterator itr;

for (itr = my_essay.begin(); itr != my_essay.end(); itr++) {

   std::cout << *itr << " ";

 }
```

It always misses the final element in the list. I feel like the problem comes from the != overload. If I add

```
std::cout << *itr;
```

After the loop, then the whole linked list is printed. So it looks like the iterator reaches the end, but doesn't print it out because its equals the end. I'm not sure if I should be changing end(), the operator overload itself, or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the code you wrote for end()?

Comment: Note that end should return the element "past-the-end", *not* the last valid element

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's generally considered valid to dereference an "end" iterator the way your `operator!=()` is effectively doing when the print loop reaches the end of your list.

An "end" iterator in C++ is traditionally a special/meta instance of an iterator type that signifies a position just past the last element in a container.

Without seeing your full implementation, my first instinct would be to maybe change your operator overload to implement special behavior when `*this` and/or `itr` are actually `Essay::end()`. Specifically, you will want to return `false` if *both* are `Essay::end()`, and `true` if one is not.